# Why are there two AVD for the same API

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I installed the `Android` SDK, and when creating an AVD, I am facing the two choices:

```
Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 17
Android 4.2.2 - API Level 17
```

What do these two versions mean?

Comment: Development-related questions are off-topic here. Try StackOverflow.com :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the names suggest, Google APIs would give you an AVD with the Google Services installed, like maps, google play services etc.

The other one, is a plain AVD, without these features.